# WHMCS how to find right tpl files in pages

Tags: whmcs

i'm using WHMCS and i want to make some changes in part of the page but its so hard and takes so much time for me to find the right tpl file and edit it in the template.

for example for this "search for domains" tab in this url =>

```
example.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register
```

where is the .tpl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register the file is at `templates/orderforms/standard_cart/adddomain.tpl`

In general, when url has cart.php, the file in cart template.

Also, you can add the following to hooks to tell you which tpl file was used for current page.

1- Create file `includes/hooks/tpl_locator.php`

2- Add the following code:

```php
<?php
add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function($vars) {
        
   error_log(print_r([$vars['currentpagelinkback'],$vars['templatefile']], true), 3, __DIR__.'/tpl_file_location.log');
});
```

3- Visit the page you want to know which tpl file is used.

4- Result will be at file `includes/hooks/tpl_file_location.log`, sample below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=1&amp;
    [1] => configureproductdomain
)
```

This was tested on WHMCS 8.0

Answer (score 1):

The tpl for cart.php?a=add&domain=register is actually located at /whmcs/templates/orderforms/standard_cart/domainregister.tpl if I understand your question.